# Not able to load logback.xml from Consul

Tags: java, spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul, consul-kv

The issue goes like this

I have all my configuration for the project in Consul KV store
The configuration includes application.yml, logback.xml and few other configurations needed by my project.

Using bootstrap.yml for Spring Cloud Consul configuration which contains
logging.config for with the URI of the configuration
URI is as follow for logging.config - http://CONSUL_SERVER_IP:CONSUL_SERVER_PORT/v1/kv/CONSUL_CONFIG_PREFIX/logback.xml?raw

Also tried passing below as argument/VM argument

```
-Dlogging.config=http://CONSUL_SERVER_IP:CONSUL_SERVER_PORT/v1/kv/CONSUL_CONFIG_PREFIX/logback.xml?raw
```

Query string 'raw' is needed to get the actual config file.

While executing the application it gives the following error

> Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.LogbackException: Unexpected filename
>   extension of file
>   [http://CONSUL_SERVER_IP:CONSUL_SERVER_PORT/v1/kv/CONSUL_CONFIG_PREFIX/logback.xml?raw].
>   Should be either .groovy or .xml  at
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:149)
>     ... 30 more

Spring boot version - 2.0.1.RELEASE

Spring cloud version - Finchley.SR2

logback classic and core version - 1.2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following solution, worked for me. Just change the URI passed to logging.config in bootstrap.yml or as VM arguments

```
http://CONSUL_SERVER_IP:CONSUL_SERVER_PORT/v1/kv/CONSUL_CONFIG_PREFIX/logback.xml?raw=true&xml
```

If you have a similar issue then add **&fileExtension** to the URI